# Show that a magma M is associative iff...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a little trouble showing this...

Show that a magma $(M,*)$ is associative if and only if the canonic application

$µ$ : $M->End(M)$, $m -> µ(m)$

is a morphism of magma.

where $µ(m)$ : $M ->M$, $m'$$->$$µ(m) (m')$ $=$ $m*m'$

Any help/comment is welcome

Comment: my main problem is that, supposing that the application is a morphism of magma, what intern law should I use in $End(M)$..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said in the comment that your main problem is the internal law on $\operatorname{End}(M)$, I'll answer that and leave the rest as an exercise. It is straightforward, but if you have any trouble, feel free to ask.

Suppose you are given $f, g\in\operatorname{End}(M)$.  Then the internal law is defined as $(f*g)(m)=(f\circ g)(m)=f(g(m))$

Comment: I found the way thanks to your help. Thank you.